# price option are not showing on whatsapp business catalog

Tags: whatsapp, business-intelligence, price, catalog

I need help from you guys to sort out the issue which is facing in my  WhatsApp business, actually, I am from Libya and I am creating a restaurant business in my WhatsApp business but after adding the whole menu but there is no option I found for entering the price

I saw some documentation of WhatsApp business some say WhatsApp business price option will show in some specific countries or not for some specific countries

but some of my few friends which are live in Pakistan and India are selling the same thing from WhatsApp business they are able to use this option but not me so I need an expert guy who has technical sound knowledge in this scenario...

please help me and let me know what is this and how this issue can be solved...

Thanks...

Comment: I think the better support is to submit your problem to [direct facebook contact support](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/contact-support).

Comment: i did that but i didn't got any answer from therm nor any solution i found from google if anyone know the solution or face this issue before please share your experience with me

Comment: Did you found the solution?? I’m getting the same problem since January